# Woocommerce Widget filter products by attributes does not work

Tags: woocommerce

I'm using a custom theme for woocommerce and on the sidebar on products archive page i'm using the "Filter products by attributes" widget but they are not displayed. I'm having the following errors:

```
WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')  GROUP BY wp_wc_product_attributes_lookup.term_id' at line 18 for query SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT product_or_parent_id) as term_count, term_id as term_count_id FROM wp_wc_product_attributes_lookup 
             LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_wc_product_attributes_lookup.product_or_parent_id = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
            INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.ID = wp_wc_product_attributes_lookup.product_or_parent_id 
            WHERE wp_posts.post_type IN ( 'product' )
            AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
             AND ( 
  wp_wc_product_attributes_lookup.product_or_parent_id NOT IN (
                SELECT object_id
                FROM wp_term_relationships
                WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (7)
            ) 
  AND 
  wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (111)
) 
            AND wp_wc_product_attributes_lookup.taxonomy='pa_latime-glafuri'
            AND wp_wc_product_attributes_lookup.term_id IN (279,280,281,282,283,284,287)
             
AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN ( )  GROUP BY wp_wc_product_attributes_lookup.term_id made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/plugins/woocommerce/templates/taxonomy-product-attribute.php'), wc_get_template, include('/themes/WindowMag/woocommerce/archive-product.php'), dynamic_sidebar, WP_Widget->display_callback, WC_Widget_Layered_Nav->widget, WC_Widget_Layered_Nav->layered_nav_list, WC_Widget_Layered_Nav->get_filtered_term_product_counts, Automattic\WooCommerce\Internal\ProductAttributesLookup\Filterer->get_filtered_term_product_counts
[03-Aug-2023 08:29:29 UTC] WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')  GROUP BY wp_wc_product_attributes_lookup.term_id' at line 18 for query SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT product_or_parent_id) as term_count, term_id as term_count_id FROM wp_wc_product_attributes_lookup 
             LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_wc_product_attributes_lookup.product_or_parent_id = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
            INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.ID = wp_wc_product_attributes_lookup.product_or_parent_id 
            WHERE wp_posts.post_type IN ( 'product' )
            AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
             AND ( 
  wp_wc_product_attributes_lookup.product_or_parent_id NOT IN (
                SELECT object_id
                FROM wp_term_relationships
                WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (7)
            ) 
  AND 
  wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (111)
) 
            AND wp_wc_product_attributes_lookup.taxonomy='pa_lungime-glafuri'
            AND wp_wc_product_attributes_lookup.term_id IN (288,289,290)
             
AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN ( )  GROUP BY wp_wc_product_attributes_lookup.term_id made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/plugins/woocommerce/templates/taxonomy-product-attribute.php'), wc_get_template, include('/themes/WindowMag/woocommerce/archive-product.php'), dynamic_sidebar, WP_Widget->display_callback, WC_Widget_Layered_Nav->widget, WC_Widget_Layered_Nav->layered_nav_list, WC_Widget_Layered_Nav->get_filtered_term_product_counts, Automattic\WooCommerce\Internal\ProductAttributesLookup\Filterer->get_filtered_term_product_counts
```

All modules and Wordpress are up to date.

Already tried the solutions from here: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/27419 but none worked.

I appreciate any suggestions